# dart recursive class method always returns null

Tags: javascript, recursion, dart

this seems to not be possible with dart? i.e. to have a class method recurse and eventually return an object? when i run a recursive method it invariably returns null IF it has recursed at least once...

example:

```
// some class method
rock throw_rock() {
  // look at its own collection of rocks
  // get a rock and do a test on it
  rock to_throw = this.rocks[53]; // lets assume its in a map at key 53...
  if (to_throw.been_thrown == 1) {
    // ok, dont throw this one, instead recurse and find another
    this.throw_rock();
  } else {
     return to_throw;
  }
}
```

in some other class or in main:

```
rock g = rock_thower.throw_rock();
// if rock thrower has had to recurse
// g will be null...
```

I am VERY new to dart and am not sure why that happens. Any ideas? Is this sane?

If not: what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would need to be `return this.throw_rock()`.

Which is to say, you want to return either your `to_throw` variable, or the result of the recursive call.

Comment: Hmm I think I see it. So when the `this.throw_rock()` portion is reached it just kind of returns null? or it doesnt re-call itself? your solution definitely worked, i just want to make sure i understand  it.

Comment: Unlike Ruby, you need to explicitly return a value from a method. In this case, `return this.throw_rock()` will recurse and return the value from the end of the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're using recursion?  Seems like a do/while might work:

```
// some class method
rock throw_rock() {
  rock to_throw;
  do {
    // look at its own collection of rocks
    // get a rock and do a test on it
    to_throw = this.rocks[53]; // lets assume its in a map at key 53...
  } while (to_throw.been_thrown != 1);
  return to_throw;
}
```

Like the recursive approach, you'll need an exit condition to handle the case when all rocks cannot be thrown.

Comment: I like it! Much cleaner. Thanks!